# Developing SQLDeveloper extensions using Python

Tags: python, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I searched a lot about **developing extensions for SQLDeveloper** and all the information I found regarding this subject involved using Java.

So, I wonder **is it possible** to develop extensions for SQLDeveloper using **Python**?

If it is, do you guys know of any guide about this process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Developer extensions [can be done only using Java, SQL or XML](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/extensions-083825.html#create) for now

Comment: I read that but still had to ask. I don't think that it is very clear whether you can use other languages/SDKs or not :(

Comment: you can run python, or jython, via the SCRIPT command in our command-line interface, SQLcl http://krisrice.blogspot.com/2015/10/sqlcl-oct-13th-edition.html << - extensions are definitely limited to Java/XML & SQL though - >>